# Ruby on Rails migration returning Killed:9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration

I'm having a real issue here with my Rails database, I created a few Migrations that held the following...

```
def change
change_column(:users, :phone, :integer, limit: 100000000)
end
```

This obviously threw a huge error, although it seemed to work, I had no idea what I was doing in all honesty, I then deleted the migration and created another trying to change the column back to its original setting, as a normal integer.

This new migration didn't work and when I attempted to migrate the database once again, it gave me this error...

```
Killed:9
```

I have no idea what this is or even how to deal with it.

Can someone please shed some light for me?
I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: Depends on your operating system. Sometimes a process that uses up way too much memory might be "shot" to avoid taking down the whole system. Either that or someone else is in there using `kill` on your process. It's worth noting you should check the current state of the database to be sure you do  need to undo the change. It may not have been applied in the first place.

Comment: @tadman I'm running this on OSX.

Comment: I've seen that intermittently, but it's hard to say what's causing it. I've never been able to reproduce it reliably, and it's happened more often with Node.js than Ruby.

Comment: @tadman In my terminal, it's attempting to load the schema migrations from the database and freezing straight there, I assumed there was an error in there but I have no idea how to change anything in there.

Comment: What's odd is the `9` signal `SIGKILL` is a pretty severe way for a process to die. Does this happen in only this project or is it now affecting others of yours? Also worth testing a different, newer version of Ruby if that's an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about [:limit option](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column) for integer attribute.

And I suggest you to use string type for phone attribute instead of integer

**Update**

Will respond in greater detail:

`:limit` option that you are using in migration is used to request maximum column length **in bytes** when used with *integer* or *binary* column types.
So in your migration you trying to change `:phone` column to integer and request for it **100000000** bytes.

Now keep in mind that, for example, the maximum integer number that can be encoded with **8 bytes** is **9 223 372 036 854 775 807**.

So all that you get when you start your migration - is out of memory.

This works with SQlite, but if you were using PostgreSQL for database - you'd get errors when you try to run this migration. Don't know about MySQL

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback, I couldn't seem to escape the error and ended up reverting back to an old version of the application I am building. Thank you for going in depth for me, I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to remove the issue by loading up an older copy of my application, although I have kept these files as I will try to fix the issue in order to find out how to remove the problem for future reference.